# Animating an ImageView from left to right - clips off the right using 100%p

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation, android-view

I am working on a very basic animation which animates a ball `ImageView` from left to right within a container. The animation works great, but when it animates to 100%p, the ball gets cut out of the container view.

The `ImageView` that animates is a static 50dp.

Is there any way to do something like 100%p-50dp to prevent the ball from clipping out of the container?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fillAfter="true"
>
<!--animate the ball-->
    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="0%p"
            android:toXDelta="100%p"
            android:duration="900"
            android:repeatMode="reverse"
            android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
</set>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a bit hacky but here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true"
>
<!--animate the ball-->
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:duration="900"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="900"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
</set>
```

basically what we do is to translate the ball both by the parent size and by its own size at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Declaring animation like that will internally use [Animation API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary). It's suggested to refrain from using [Animation API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary) if possible. I'm not sure whether it's possible to achieve that using by xml only, that's why I would suggest using [Animator API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator) instead, particularly [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator).

```
    ball.setOnClickListener {

        val animateToX = if (it.translationX == 0F) container.width - ball.width.toFloat()
        else 0F

        it.animate().translationX(animateToX)

    }
```

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To translation in x position (*Left to right*) upto a perticular distance, here 200f is the tranlation distance.

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, View.TRANSLATION_X, 200f)
animator.start()
```

To show a smooth or slow tranlation use duration property (*by default duration is 300*).

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, View.TRANSLATION_X, 200f)
animator.duration = 1000
animator.start()
```

To tranlate back to the same position use repetCout and repeatMode.

```
val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(star, View.TRANSLATION_X, 200f)
animator.duration = 1000
animator.repeatCount = 1
animator.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
animator.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

Left to Right Animation

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p" />

</set>
```

Hope it will help you.